# Why macro meant for sheets(13) being executed at sheets(12)

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I wrote a code to change the color format of certain cells of every sheets (I have 12 similar sheets[Sheets(1)-Sheets(12)];and a summary sheet (Sheets(13)).

When I run it, the code that I intend to be executed on Sheets(13) is being executed at Sheets(12). Of course I can separate the code, and execute the code for 13th sheet exclusively but I would like to understand why it does not work.

```
Sub forEachWs()
Dim x As Long
Dim ws As Sheets

For x = 1 To 12
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(x).Activate
    Call changecolormonths
    Range("A2").Select
Next x

If x = 13 Then
Call changesummarycolor   'this is the code that is wrongly executed at sheet 12 
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Now that you changed the code my comment does not make sense.  but with the new code you do not activate sheet 13 so it is using the last active sheet which is 12.

Comment: You should pass the sheet as a variable into the `changesummarycolor` sub and avoid the whole activate.

Comment: x=13 because of the `for` loop. Next x after 12 is 13 and the loop exits. But even if x is 13, the code inside the loop didn' run for x=13 (only for x from 1 to 12). The simplest thing to do is add a `thisworkbook.Sheets(13).activate` before calling `changesummarycolor`, even if i do not agry with the over using of `select` or `activate`.

Comment: @ScottCraner hi..if u don't mind,can you post the code nonetheless..I appreciate anything that I can learn from it..

Comment: I can't because I do not know the code for `changesummarycolor`

Answer (score 0):

You should code explicitly. Avoid the usage of `Select` and `ActiveWorksheet`. Do not reference a range without stating the sheet up front (on which you wish to use a particular range). Don't allow VBA to make assumptions for you but tell VBA what you want. Be specific.

Here is your code rewritten with explicit references. This should solve your problem.

```
Option Explicit

Sub forEachWs()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wsSUM As Worksheet
Dim bolfound As Boolean

bolfound = False
For Each wsSUM In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If wsSUM.Name = "Summary" Then
        bolfound = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next wsSUM
If bolfound = False Then
    MsgBox "Couldn't find the summary sheet." & Chr(10) & "Aborting..."
    Exit Sub
End If

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> wsSUM.Name Then
        Call changecolormonths(ws, wsSUM)
        ws.Activate
        ws.Range("A2").Select
    Else
        Call changesummarycolor(wsSUM)
    End If
Next ws

End Sub

'below code are meant for Sheets(1) to Sheets(12)
Sub changecolormonths(ws As Worksheet, wsSUM As Worksheet)

Dim headercolor As Long
Dim proccolor As Long

headercolor = wsSUM.Range("B24").Value
proccolor = wsSUM.Range("B25").Value

With ws
    .Range("A1:H1,L8:M8,K16:M16,L32:N32,L40:N40").Interior.Pattern = xlSolid  'header,total color
    .Range("A1:H1,L8:M8,K16:M16,L32:N32,L40:N40").Interior.ColorIndex = headercolor

    .Range("A1:H1,L8:M8,K16:M16,L32:N32,L40:N40").Font.ColorIndex = 2

    .Range("K9:K15,K33:K39").Interior.Pattern = xlSolid  'procedure
    .Range("K9:K15,K33:K39").Interior.ColorIndex = proccolor
End With

End Sub

'below code are meant for Sheets(13)
Sub changesummarycolor(wsSUM As Worksheet)

Dim headercolor As Long
Dim proccolor As Long

With wsSUM
    headercolor = .Range("B24").Value
    proccolor = .Range("B25").Value

    .Range("B4:N4 , A12: N12 , N5: N11").Interior.Pattern = xlSolid  'summary header,total color
    .Range("B4:N4 , A12: N12 , N5: N11").Interior.ColorIndex = headercolor

    .Range("B4: N4 , A12: N12 , N5: N11").Font.ColorIndex = 2  'summary procedure

    .Range("A5:A11").Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
    .Range("A5:A11").Interior.ColorIndex = proccolor
End With

End Sub
```

<sub>Note, that I do not have your Excel file and therefore couldn't test the above code. I merely rewrote it off the top of my head. Hence, it might need some tweaking. Yet, the changes were minimal and I am pretty confident that it should run as intended. Still, feel free to tell me if anything goes wrong. :)</sub>

Comment: Finally able to try your code.. It gives erro "Compile error: Method or data member not found " when it rns to the subroutine                                       Sub changecolormonths(ws As Worksheet, wsSUM As Worksheet),,Also, do  u mind to explain when should we write like this [changecolormonths(ws, wsSUM)]-- call the subroutine and have something in brackets behind it?

Comment: I just made two minor adjustments to the code. Now it works flawlessly. Yet, I am not sure if you meant to write `headercolor = .Range("B24").Value` or `headercolor = .Range("B24").Interior.ColorIndex`. I will leave it to you to adjust it if necessary. The squared brackets you are proposing are not necessary (as you can see in the above code). Your question: `...having something in brackets behind it?` I do not quite understand. Please elaborate what you want to achieve by doing so.